# Retrieving property from first item with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there a simpler way to write this query in Linq:

```
var prioritiy = db.Requirements.Where(r => r.ID == rowID).Select(r => r.Priority).First();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "simpler" as in "less code", your self-answer is already the most compact:

```
db.Requirements.First(r => r.ID == rowID).Priority;
```

If you mean "simpler" as in "less database overhead", then your original version is slightly better:

```
db.Requirements.Where(r => r.ID == rowID).Select(r => r.Priority).First();
```

Why? As @IvanStoev pointed out in the comments, LINQ execution is deferred until you call a "finishing" method like `First()`. If you're using SQL on the backend, the second example will be translated into a SQL statement that retrieves only the Priority field from the database, whereas the first example will retrieve all fields for the matching row.

This is, IMO, firmly in the realm of unnecessary micro-optimizations, unless this code runs millions of times or the full database object has tons of columns. Unless you're doing something crazy, just use the style that you like!

Comment: First off, it's the opposite - the original query will select and return a single field from database, while other variants will return all the fields from the database, create and fully populate a new object with them, and finally take a single property from that object. So while OP landed on a "simpler way", it's definitely not a good (better) solution. What about the first part explaining the unnecessary work of where, select and first chain, it's just ridiculous - everyone know LINQ is deferred and doesn't work this way.

Comment: In fact the only true statement in this post is the one saying that second query is equivalent to the third query.

Comment: @IvanStoev That's what I get for posting an answer when I'm tired. Thanks for the correction, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry mate, that's a different story - no more explanation needed, I know what that means :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Haha :) fixed! (and more coffee ingested)

Answer (score 2):

Never mind.  I just figured out that by applying First() initially, I return an object which contains the property I'm looking for.  The code turns into:

```
var priority = db.Requirements.First(r => r.ID == rowID).Priority;
```

Answer (score 0):

a safer version in Visual Studio 2015

```
var priority = db.Requirements.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ID == rowID)?.Priority;
```

of if you call that often, you can use a `LookUp`

```
var lookup = db.Requirements.ToLookup(r => r.ID, r => r.Priority);

var priority = lookup[rowID].FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Note that this isn't equivalent to the given code. If a match isn't found, the original will throw an exception (in the `First` call), while yours will return `null`.

Comment: @Slai, you've mentioned a good practice for handling exceptions.  Based on the context of how I was using the statement (which I admittedly did not supply in the question), I wanted the exception to be thrown if no match was found.  Alejandro, that was a great observation.